# How to pass Object from java class to another java class

Tags: java

I created an instance of a class in java as following:

`ABC ab = new ABC();`

I want to access this instant `ab` in another class `XYZ`. How to make this Object available in class XYZ?

Answer (score 8):

It is difficult to answer your question without more specific information about your problem, but this would certainly work:

You can use a setter to initialize an instance variable in your other class if you want to use it everywhere in that class:

```
class someClass {
   void someMethod() {
      ABC ab = new ABC();
      XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
      xyz.setABC(ab);
   }
}

class XYZ {
   ABC ab;
   //...
   void setABC(ABC ab) {
     this.ab = ab;
   }
   //...
   void doSomething() {
      // do something with instance variable ab
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do what you want to achieve. Some of them might be as follows:

**Passing the object reference through a `constructor`** 
Here, you would explicitly pass the reference of your reference class when you're creating an object of the actual class.

```
public class ActualClass{
    private ReferenceClass refClassObject;
    
    /**
    * Passing through a constructor
    */
    public ActualClass(ReferenceClass refClassObject){
        this.refClassObject = refClassObject;
    }
}

class ReferenceClass{
    /**
    * Your implementation of the class
    */
}
```

**Using getter/setter methods**
In this approach, you would pass the reference of your object through explict `public setXX()` methods. This approach is more flexible because you can update the reference object as and when you want to (think `polymorphism`). As an example:

```
public class ActualClass{
    private ReferenceClass refClassObject;
    
    public ActualClass(){
    }
    
    public void setReferenceClass(ReferenceClass refClassObject){
        this.refClassObject = refClassObject;
    }
    
    public ReferenceClass getReferenceClass(){
        return refClassObject;
    }
}

class ReferenceClass{
    /**
    * Your implementation of the class
    */
}
```

**Using a combination of constructors and getters/setters**
For added flexibility, you might want to initialize your Actual class object with a reference. However if you would also want to keep the option of changing the reference at object at a later stage, go for a combination of both #1 & #2 that I specified above.

```
public class ActualClass{
    private ReferenceClass refClassObject;
    
    public ActualClass(){
    }
    
    public ActualClass(ReferenceClass refClassObject){
        this.refClassObject = refClassObject;
    }
    
    public void setReferenceClass(ReferenceClass refClassObject){
        this.refClassObject = refClassObject;
    }
    
    public ReferenceClass getReferenceClass(){
        return refClassObject;
    }
}

class ReferenceClass{
    /**
    * Your implementation of the class
    */
}
```

Which one should you choose? Well it would depend on your implementation and requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is exactlty same as Doug Ramsey [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048320/1395259)
I tried to explain with the same logic.

```
  public class A {
        public void m1() {
            System.out.println("inside m1 method");
            ABC ab = new ABC(); // 2 object is made and reference is given to ab 
            XYZ xyz = new XYZ();  3 object is made and reference is given to xyz 
            xyz.send(ab); // 4 THIS IS WHAT YOUR QUESTION MEANS
        }
    }


    class XYZ {
       ABC ab;
       //...
       void send(ABC ab) { // 5
         this.ab = ab;
         System.out.println("inside send");
         callme(); 
       }
       //...
       void callme() { // 6
           System.out.println("A is : "+ab.a);
           System.out.println("b is : "+ab.b);
          // do something with instance variable ab
       } 
    }

public class ABC {
    int a = 10;
    static int b= 20;
    public static void main(String[] args) // called first
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have ABC ab; in class XYZ, doesn't will this Object be initialized to null.

Comment: @user1602657 first of all the main() gets called by the jvm, as it is declared as static.

Comment: I have a class DataCI, I have written below code:
RegisterRequisitioner regReq = new RegisterRequisitioner();
regReq.DataCI(buyerAdmin);
And a class RegisterRequisitioner having below code:
public void DataCI(DataCI buyerAdmin1) {
      this.buyerAdmin1 = buyerAdmin1;
    }

But buyerAdmin1 in RegisterRequisitioner is coming as null.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to pass object parameter to one class to another.

- Passing parameter to a method

  ```
  public void passMethod(ABC ab) {
  }
  ```
- Passing parameter to a constructor

  ```
  public class XYZ {

      public XYZ(ABC ab) {               
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but If I'm correct you want to transfer an Object into another class to be used.

In order to do that you need a few things

Class XYZ has to have a constructor to take in the parameter "Object" it would something like

```
class XYZ{
    private Object ab
    public XYZ(Object ab){
        this.ab = ab;//This is the constructor called when you create an XYZ object, and want to use the Object ab in XYZ
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package demo;

class ABC{
     void disp(xyz arg1){
        System.out.println("runing disp method in pratics");
        System.out.println("x value:"+arg1.x);
        arg1.test();
     }

}

class xyz{
     int x = 67;
     void test(){
        System.out.println("runing test method in pratics");
     }
}

class pratics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ABC ab=new ABC();
        ab.disp(new xyz());
    }

}
```